# Weak homotopy type of the Cech Nerve

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Let ${\cal U} = \{U_i\}_{i\in J}$ be an open cover of a topological space $X$, where the indexing set $J$ is assumed to be well-ordered. Then the Cech nerve is the "simplicial space without degeneracies''
$$
N{\cal U}\quad  := \quad \coprod_i U_i \substack{\leftarrow \\ \leftarrow  } \coprod_{i<j} U_i\cap U_j  \substack{\leftarrow \\ \leftarrow  \\ \leftarrow }\coprod_{i<j<k} U_i\cap U_j \cap U_k \substack{\leftarrow \\ \leftarrow  \\ \leftarrow \\ \leftarrow }\quad \cdots
$$
Let  $|N{\cal U}|$ denote geometric realization of $N{\cal U}$; it is a quotient space of the disjoint union $\amalg_k X_k \times \Delta^k$, where $X_k$ is the space of $k$-simplices.

There is an evident map $|N{\cal U}| \to X$.

**Question:** is this map always a weak homotopy equivalence?

If so, is there a well-known reference for this?

**Note:** If $X$ is paracompact, then it seems to me that the map is a homotopy equivalence. This can be proved by adapting an argument that Graeme Segal gives in the paper, *Classifying spaces and spectral sequences.*  Furthermore, in the special case of a cover with two members, the result appears in Peter May's, *Weak equivalences and quasifibrations.*  However, I do not know of a reference in the general case.

**Note Added:** User skupers points out that the result appears in Dugger and Isaksen's paper, *Topological hypercovers and ${\Bbb A}_1$-realizations.*

**Another Note Added:** As Dugger and Isaksen point out, one can reduce to the paracompact case as follows:  Given a map $f:S^n \to X$, we can take the preimages of the $U_i$ to obtain an open cover $\{f^{-1}U_i\}$ of $S^n$. As the sphere is paracompact the result is true for this cover and we deduce that the map $|N{\cal U}|\to X$ is onto on homotopy groups.  A relative version of this argument also shows that the map is one-to-one on homotopy groups. Hence, the result does follow from the method of Graeme Segal. Dugger and Isaksen also provide a different proof.

Comment: I think this is Dugger-Isaksen, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-003-0607-y.

Comment: @AndreasBlass no, the $U_i$ don't need to be contractible. You need to use the topology here: if the cover as one member $X$, then the realization as a simplicial space without degeneracies is $X$, so the result is true in this case.

Comment: @skupers Yes, that's it! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll delete my incorrect comment.

Comment: The most General Version of asuch results is in section 6 of https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-212/issue-2/Stable-moduli-spaces-of-high-dimensional-manifolds/10.1007/s11511-014-0112-7.full.

Comment: This immediately implies the Statement you are looking for.